# Using Linq to remove from set where key exists in other set?

Tags: c#, linq

What is the proper way to do set subtraction using Linq?  I have a List of 8000+ banks where I want to remove a portion of those based on the routing number.  The portion is in another List and routing number is the key property to both.  Here is a simplification:

```
public class Bank
{
    public string RoutingNumber { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

var removeThese = new List<string>() { "111", "444", "777" };

var banks = new List<Bank>()
{
    new Bank() { RoutingNumber = "111", Name = "First Federal" },
    new Bank() { RoutingNumber = "222", Name = "Second Federal" },
    new Bank() { RoutingNumber = "333", Name = "Third Federal" },
    new Bank() { RoutingNumber = "444", Name = "Fourth Federal" },
    new Bank() { RoutingNumber = "555", Name = "Fifth Federal" },
    new Bank() { RoutingNumber = "666", Name = "Sixth Federal" },
    new Bank() { RoutingNumber = "777", Name = "Seventh Federal" },
    new Bank() { RoutingNumber = "888", Name = "Eight Federal" },
    new Bank() { RoutingNumber = "999", Name = "Ninth Federal" },
};

var query = banks.Remove(banks.Where(x => removeThese.Contains(x.RoutingNumber)));
```

Comment: +1 for actually asking a well rounded question.

Comment: Such nice concise answers, I regret being able to accept only one. Thanks to all.

Comment: Do you want to remove that banks from the list as mentioned or do you want to know which banks need to be removed suggested by your code in the last line?

Comment: Remove from banks.  Several people, including yourself, gave acceptable answers and they all work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
var toRemove = banks.Where(x => removeThese.Contains(x.RoutingNumber)).ToList();
var query = banks.RemoveAll(x => toRemove.Contains(x));
```

The first step is to make sure that you don't have to re-run that first query over and over again, whenever `banks` changes.

This should work too:

```
var query = banks.Except(toRemove);
```

as your second line.

**EDIT**

Tim Schmelter pointed out that for `Except` to work, you need to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`.

So you could implement it like so:

```
public override string ToString()
{
   ... any serialization will do, for instance JSON or CSV or XML ...
   ... OR any serialization that identifies the object quickly, such as:
   return "Bank: " + this.RoutingNumber;
}


public override bool Equals(System.Object obj)
{
    return ((obj is Bank) && (this.ToString().Equals(obj.ToString()));
}


public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return this.ToString().GetHashCode();
}
```

Comment: `banks.Except(toRemove)` works only if `Bank` overrides `Equals` and `GetHashCode`.

Comment: Interesting, I will have to learn how to implement this approach.  It could produce cleaner code, I would think.

Comment: You should check if they have the same `RoutingNumber` since that seem to be the identifier. I would also not use `ToString` in `Equals` and `GetHashCode` since that might change in future (f.e. for debugging purposes) and you forget that you have to change it here also. In general `ToString` is unrelated to `Equals/GetHashCode`. But you should check first if the other object is a `Bank` at all since that is most important.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: A good quick serialization in `ToString()` would lead to the implementation above where `Equals` and `GetHashCode` can rely on the unicity and identifying quality of the `ToString()` implementation. If just checking the `RoutingNumber` is in this case a good implementation for `Equals`, then obviously that would be a lot faster. But still, the solution as outlined above will do the trick.

Comment: -1: Your proposed implementation of `Equals` / `GetHashCode` is disastrous, and it only works partially (e.g.: if I have a `string` instance that contains the `ToString()` serialization of `Bank`, then they will compare as Equal according `Bank.Equals`, but **not** according to `String.Equals`). Also, defining a serialization format in `ToString` is *a lot* more work than writing simple, usual `Equals` and `GetHashCode` implementations.

Comment: Jean: you are right of course. Writing `return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(this);` is a *lot* more work than writing simple, usual `Equals` and `GetHashCode` implementations. Anyway, it's just a possible implementation that would solve the problem. Your mileage may vary and handle with care.

Comment: @RoyDictus: The work in serializing an object is not in the implementation, it is in the specification. But OK. Touché. What about the fundamental incorrectness of doing it that way?

Comment: The worst thing is, you could easily export the implementation to an `IEqualityComparer<Bank>` implementation and my main objections would actually go away.

Comment: @JeanHominal: I don't think this is fundamentally incorrect. `ToString()` is a good home for serialization or you can put anything identifying in there and use that to implement `Equals` IF your class is large -- that would be a *lot* less work than writing a long list of property equals checks. Remember that the model OP used is a simplification. So if this is a large class with many properties just basing `Equals` on type and serialization is a good option. And if `ToString()` is uniquely identifying, then surely `Equals` and `GetHashCode` can base themselves upon it. My 2 cents.

Comment: It is fundamentally incorrect because I can find (x, y) so that `x.Equals(y)` is not equal to `y.Equals(x)` (cf. the MSDN page about [`Object.Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx)). You could fix that by putting a type check in `Equals`.

Comment: Really?? And you are saying that there is no type check in my `Equals` implementation??

Comment: @RoyDictus: That will teach me to write without reading more carefully the edited version.

Comment: This answer is unnecessarily complicated compared to other answers in the thread. For example Jon's answer gives two independent one-liner solutions that are both fast, correct and easy to read.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: This answer also two independent solutions. The second is the most readable and useful but it requires that the Bank class implements certain constructs, then it provides a simple implementation of those constructs. I don't see the necessity of your comment.

Answer (score 7):

Generally it's less work to just pull out the ones you need rather than deleting the ones you don't i.e.

```
var query = myList.Where(x => !removeThese.Contains(x.RoutingNumber));
```

Answer (score 5):

Filtering of this type is generally done with generic LINQ constructs:

```
banks = banks.Where(bank => !removeThese.Contains(bank.RoutingNumber)).ToList();
```

In this specific case you can also use [`List<T>.RemoveAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx) to do the filtering in-place, which will be faster:

```
banks.RemoveAll(bank => removeThese.Contains(bank.RoutingNumber));
```

Also, for performance reasons, if the amount of routing numbers to remove is large you should consider putting them into a `HashSet<string>` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Either use  the Linq extension methods `Where` and `ToList` to create a new list or  use [`List.RemoveAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx) which is more efficient since it modifies the original list:

```
banks = banks.Where(x => !removeThese.Contains(x.RoutingNumber)).ToList();
banks.RemoveAll(x => removeThese.Contains(x.RoutingNumber));
```

Of course you have to reverse the condition since the former keeps what `Where` leaves  and the latter removes what the predicate in `RemoveAll` returns.

Comment: Would using `Any()` be more efficient than using `Contains()`? Or would it be the same?

Comment: @Bob.: (nearly) the same, both stop as soon as they found one, similar to a `break` in a loop. `Contains` is more readable but works only if the underlying type(in this case of the `RoutingNumber`) overrides `Equals`.

Comment: @Bob. Also, with `Any` you would have to give a lambda arrow as argument. That would mean two nested lambdas. The compiler would have to generate a real method for your second lambda, and create a delegate instance whose `Method` was the `MethodInfo` of that generated method, and whose `Target` was an instance of some compiler-generated nested class. So it would be a bit more complex under the hood. Still very fast, though, so readability is also important.

Comment: And note that the second solution really uses no Linq at all (the `Contains` is an instance method on `List<>`), so it is a true .NET 2.0 solution (except that `=>` was not in the C# syntax when .NET 2.0 was young).

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using `RemoveAll()`?

```
var query = banks.RemoveAll(p => removeThese.Contains(p.RoutingNumber));
```

This will remove the any values from `banks` where a matching record is present in `removeThese`.

`query` will contain the number of records removed from the list.

Note: The orginal variable `banks` will be updated directly by this query; a reassignment is not required.

Comment: You should explain what `query` is afterwards. It is an integer giving the number of banks that were actually removed.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I have expanded the answer.  Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

You can use RemoveAll()

```
var removedIndexes = banks.RemoveAll(x => removeThese.Contains(x.RoutingNumber));
```

or

```
banks = banks.Where(bank => !removeThese.Contains(bank.RoutingNumber)).ToList();
```

Comment: No, it does not use Linq. The methods `List<>.RemoveAll` and `List<>.Contains` are not a part of Linq. Note that your `query` is just an integer.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen thanks for correcting us all. It was something I wrote on this page without executing. It just shows how much I trust debugging/intellisense and other tools I use when coding C#.